# How do I use a UIButton Action to change the NSArray that is used to populate a UITableView?

Tags: uitableview, ios4, nsarray, ibaction

I am making a new app that has four sets of data that are very similar. I want to make four UIButtons to navigate to one UITabBar with four UITableViews. I don't want to make four buttons that push to four sets of tableviews.  I figure making an app with 13 UIViews would make it bigger than it needs to be. So, I have to figure out how to make the UIButton action change the data the tables receive. I am working on this project actively. Any suggestions would be helpful. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to change a table views data source you need to change what is returned from numberOfRowsInSection on your table delegate. One way I have done this is to use an enum to represent which set of data I want to use and have a local variable to save which one is selected

```
typedef enum
{
    DataSetOne,
    DataSetTwo
} DataSetEnum

@property(nonatomic, retain) DataSetEnum dataset;
@property(nonatomic, retain) NSArray *datasetone;
@property(nonatomic, retain) NSArray *datasettwo;

- (void) viewDidLoad
{
     dataset = DataSetOne;
}
- (IBAction) buttonPressed
{
     dataset = DataSetTwo;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
     if(dataset == DataSetOne)
     {
          return [self.datasetone count];
     }
     else if(dataset == DataSetTwo)
     {
          return [self.datasettwo count];
     }
}
```

And then in cellForRowAtIndexPath

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
     if(dataset == DataSetOne)
     {
           //configure cell
     }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I will definitely try your method out.

Answer (score 0):

If your data is similar you could just set a data from each button's `IBAction` variable:

```
NSArray* data = ...
```

Then in your button method:

```
-(IBAction*)clickedButton1:(id)sender {
    data = [self getButton1Data]
    [self reloadAll]
}
```

Comment: Thank you, that sounds like a fine idea. I will try it.

Comment: I decided not to do it like this, so there will be no answer.